How To Mock the Create SMS message function Using Twilio in a Jest Test
Trying to test my Twilio API call, but can't mock the create message for some reason,
This is my terminal error log:
 TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'create')

      27 |   it('should send a verification code via SMS (mocked)', async () => {
      28 |     const mockCreate = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ sid: 'some-message-sid' });
    > 29 |     twilio.messages.create = mockCreate;
         |                           ^
      30 |
      31 |     const response = await request(app)
      32 |       .post('/send-verification-code')

      at _callee2$ (server/server.test.js:29:27)
      at call (server/server.test.js:2:1)
      at Generator.tryCatch (server/server.test.js:2:1)
      at Generator._invoke [as next] (server/server.test.js:2:1)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (server/server.test.js:2:1)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (server/server.test.js:2:1)
      at _next (server/server.test.js:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (server/server.test.js:2:1)

server.test.js
require('@babel/register')({
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
}); 

import request from 'supertest';
import app from './server.mjs'; 
import twilio from 'twilio';

describe('Server endpoints', () => {
  it('should send a verification code via SMS (mocked)', async () => {
    const mockCreate = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ sid: 'some-message-sid' });
    twilio.messages.create = mockCreate;

    const response = await request(app)
      .post('/send-verification-code')
      .send({ formattedPhoneNumber: '+447720761143' });

    expect(response.status).toBe(200);
    expect(response.body).toHaveProperty('verificationCode');
    expect(mockCreate).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      body: expect.stringContaining('verification code'),
      from: twilioPhoneNumber,
      to: '+447720761143',
    });
  });
});

--
server.mjs
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';  // Added for parsing request bodies
import twilio from 'twilio';  // Added for Twilio integration

dotenv.config();
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));  // Added for parsing URL-encoded bodies
app.set('trust proxy', true);
app.use(cors());

const port = 3001;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

// Twilio API Endpoint

// Twilio credentials

const twilioAccountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const twilioAuthToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const twilioPhoneNumber = process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER;

const client = twilio(twilioAccountSid, twilioAuthToken);

// Endpoint to send verification code via SMS

app.post('/send-verification-code', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('Endpoint reached: /send-verification-code');
  const { formattedPhoneNumber } = req.body;

  // Log the received data
  console.log('Received request with formattedPhoneNumber:', formattedPhoneNumber);

  try {
    // Generate a random verification code
    const verificationCode = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);

    // Send SMS using Twilio
    await client.messages.create({
      body: `G-${verificationCode} is your Google verification code.`,
      from: twilioPhoneNumber,
      to: formattedPhoneNumber,
    })
    .then(message => {
      console.log('Twilio API call successful:', message.sid);
      console.log('Verification code:', verificationCode)
      res.json({ 
        sid: message.sid,
        verificationCode: verificationCode,
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Twilio API call error:', error.response ? error.response.data : error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in try-catch block:', error.response ? error.response.data : error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

I have tried creating a client and service file and then running the test on that, but it didn't work for me for some reason.
Tried tinkering with the syntax in parts, but also couldn't find a fix.

Using jest you can mock out the Twilio SDK by specifying the following code prior to your describe block
const createMessageMock = jest.fn();
jest.mock('twilio', () => ({
  Twilio: jest.fn(() => ({
    messages: {
      create: createMessageMock
    }
  }))
}));

Then in each test, you can set the mock implementation to control what create message returns i.e.
createMessageMock.mockImplementation(() => ({ sid: 'SMaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' }));

A complete example can be seen at https://github.com/RJPearson94/scheduled-message-sender/blob/main/test/lambda.spec.ts
Hope this helps
